# How do i create or where can i find the clientSecret key for Stripe elements mount?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

***UPDATED CODE***

Hello i want to use Stripe in order users can create a subscription. I am confused about the client Secret key.

I am using ionic 5 angular 14 capacitor 5 WITH PHP AS BACKEND.

so i used PHP to createIntent before i created a customer because i want to use the payment elements for the user to put the card credentials in the provided by Stripe input fields and via paymentElement. That shouldn't be the case right? Because you should have a cuswtomerId.

Anyway now the paymentElements are ok the inputs for the card are shown BUT only with my pk_live key not the test one (pk_test.......) Thats weird too right? Because i want to test first.

component.ts

```
    import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { UserData } from 'src/app/services/user-data/user-data';
import {
  loadStripe,
  Stripe,
  StripeElements,
  StripeCardElement,
  StripeElementsOptions,
  StripeElement,
  StripeCardNumberElement,
} from '@stripe/stripe-js';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-subscription',
  templateUrl: 'subscription.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['subscription.page.scss'],
})
export class SubscriptionPage implements AfterViewInit {
  stripe: Stripe;
  elements: StripeElements;
   paymentElement: StripeCardElement | StripeCardNumberElement; // <-- Add this statement here
  clientSecret: string; 

  appearance: StripeElementsOptions['appearance'] = {
    theme: 'stripe',
    variables: {
      colorPrimary: '#0570de',
      colorBackground: '#ffffff',
      colorText: '#30313d',
      colorDanger: '#df1b41',
      fontFamily: 'Ideal Sans, system-ui, sans-serif',
      spacingUnit: '2px',
      borderRadius: '4px',
      // Define other custom styling variables as needed
    },
  };

  menuOpenCopyright: boolean = false;
  user: any = {};
  email: string = '';
  uid: string = '';

  modalOpen: boolean = false;
  cardInputFocused: boolean = false;

  cardDetail: any = {
    name: '',
    cardNumber: '',
    expiryDate: '',
    securityCode: '',
  };

  constructor(
    public router: Router,
    public userData: UserData,
  ) {
    this.user = this.userData.getUserData();
    this.uid = this.user.uid;
    this.email = this.user.email;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Fetch the clientSecret before initializing Stripe
    this.userData.getClientSecret()
      .then(clientSecret => {
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
        return this.initializeStripe(); // Initialize Stripe after getting clientSecret
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.createPaymentElement(this.clientSecret);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error initializing Stripe:', error);
      });
  }

  async initializeStripe() {
    const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_live_51HiSUoGozbMWFnurKP*********8'); 
    this.stripe = await stripePromise;
    this.elements = this.stripe.elements();
  }

  createPaymentElement(clientSecret) {
    if (!this.stripe) {
      console.error('Stripe is not initialized.');
      return;
    }

    this.elements = this.stripe.elements({
      clientSecret: clientSecret, // Replace with your actual client secret
    });
  
    // Create the payment element
    const paymentElementOptions = {
      // Add any specific options for the payment element
    };
    this.paymentElement = this.elements.create('payment', paymentElementOptions) as unknown as StripeCardElement | StripeCardNumberElement;   
    // Mount the payment element to the DOM
    this.paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');

 
  }

//function that users pressed button to subscribe
  async subscribe() {
    try {
  
      // Create the PaymentMethod using the payment Element
      const { paymentMethod, error } = await this.stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        type: 'card',
        card: this.paymentElement,
      });
  
      if (!error) {
        console.log('PaymentMethod created:', paymentMethod);
  
        // Continue with your logic for creating a customer, setupIntent, and subscription
        const paymentData = {
          email: this.cardDetail.email,
          paymentMethodId: paymentMethod.id,
          uid: this.uid,
          name: this.cardDetail.name,
          business: this.cardDetail.business,
        };
  
        this.userData.createCustomer(paymentData).subscribe((customerResponse: any) => {
          if (customerResponse.success) {
            const customerId = customerResponse.customer.id;
            console.log('Customer created:', customerResponse.customer);
            this.userData.createSetupIntent(customerId).subscribe((setupIntentResponse: any) => {
              if (setupIntentResponse.success) {
                const setupIntentClientSecret = setupIntentResponse.setupIntent.client_secret;
  
                // Create a subscription with the saved payment method
                const planId = 'price_1O2VVjGozbMWFnurNiXUurH7'; // Replace with your actual pricing plan ID
                this.userData.createSubscription(customerId, planId, setupIntentClientSecret).subscribe((subscriptionResponse: any) => {
                  if (subscriptionResponse.success) {
                    console.log('Subscription successful:', subscriptionResponse.subscription);
                  } else {
                    console.error(subscriptionResponse.error);
                  }
                });
              } else {
                console.error(setupIntentResponse.error);
              }
            });
          } else {
            console.error(customerResponse.error);
            console.error('Error creating customer:', customerResponse.error);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.error('PaymentMethod creation error:', error);
        // Handle the error if PaymentMethod creation fails
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in subscribe:', error);
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

userData.ts functions (NOTE: in the getClientSecret function that calls the createSetupIntent php function before anything else i dont send a customerId as i should. How am i going to create a customer thus ID without the paymentData?)

```
createCustomer(payment) {
        const url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'createCustomer';
        const data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
            api_signature: this.api_signature,
            payment: payment
        });

        return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: this.options });
    }


    getClientSecret(): Promise<string> {
        const url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'createSetupIntent'; // Replace with your endpoint
        return this.http.post(url, {}).toPromise()
          .then((response: any) => response.clientSecret)
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching clientSecret:', error);
            throw error;
          });
      }
      
    createSetupIntent(customerId: string) {
        const url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'createSetupIntent';
        const data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
            customerId: customerId
        });
        return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: this.options });
    };

    createSubscription(customerId: string, planId: string, setupIntentClientSecret: string) {
        const url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'createSubscription';
        const data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
            customerId: customerId,
            planId: planId,
            setupIntentClientSecret: setupIntentClientSecret, // Pass setupIntentClientSecret
        });
        return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: this.options });
    }
```

php function (Stripe works)

```
    function createCustomer() {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $response['success'] = true; 

    $requestData = $request->post('payment');

    $userEmail = $requestData['email'];
    $token = $requestData['token'];
    $uid = $requestData['uid'];
    $name = $requestData['name'];
    $business = $requestData['business'];

    $cardHolderEmail = $requestData['cardHolderEmail']; 

    try {
        // Create a new Stripe customer
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
            'email' => $userEmail, // User's email
            'source' => $token, 
        ]);

        // Save the Stripe customer ID in your user's record
        // This is a placeholder for updating your user's table with the customer ID
        // Adjust this code according to your database structure
        $userStripeCustomerId = $customer->id;


        $db = getDB();

        // Save the $userStripeCustomerId in your database
        // Example SQL query to update the user's record with the Stripe customer ID
        // Replace 'your-database-connection' with your actual database connection code
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET customer_id = :customer_id WHERE email = :email";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":customer_id", $userStripeCustomerId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $userEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

         // Determine the value of 'is_business' based on the 'business' field
        $isBusiness = ($business === 'YES') ? 'YES' : 'NO';

        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO payment_details (uid, name_on_card, card_holder_email, is_business) VALUES (:uid, :name, :card_holder_email, :is_business)";
        $stmt1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
        $stmt1->bindParam(":uid", $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt1->bindParam(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt1->bindParam(":card_holder_email", $cardHolderEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt1->bindParam(":is_business", $isBusiness, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt1->execute();

        $response = [
            'customer' => $customer,
            'success' => true,
        ];
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
        $response = [
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            'success' => false,
        ];
    }
   
    // Send the response as JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}

function createSetupIntent() {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $response['success'] = true;

    // Retrieve the customer ID from the request
    $customerId = $request->post('customerId');

    try {
        // Create a Setup Intent for the customer
        $setupIntent = \Stripe\SetupIntent::create([
            'customer' => $customerId,
        ]);
        $clientSecret = $setupIntent->client_secret;

        $response = [
            'setupIntent' => $setupIntent,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
            'success' => true,
        ];
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
        $response = [
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            'success' => false,
        ];
    }

    // Send the response as JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}

function createSubscription() {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $response['success'] = true;

    // Retrieve the customer ID and plan ID from the request
    $customerId = $request->post('customerId');
    $planId = $request->post('planId');

    try {
        // Create a subscription for the customer
        $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
            'customer' => $customerId,
            'items' => [
                [
                    'price' => $planId,
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        $response = [
            'subscription' => $subscription,
            'success' => true,
        ];
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
        $response = [
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            'success' => false,
        ];
    }

    // Send the response as JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

and on console i am getting

```
    subscription.page.ts:170 Error in subscribe: IntegrationError: Invalid value for createPaymentMethod: card was `payment` Element, which cannot be used to create card PaymentMethods.
    at v3/:1:493961
    at ne (v3/:1:184827)
    at re (v3/:1:185082)
    at v3/:1:337961
    at Xr (v3/:1:338011)
    at e.<anonymous> (v3/:1:388774)
    at e._createPaymentMethod (v3/:1:91285)
    at e.o (v3/:1:422082)
    at SubscriptionPage.<anonymous> (subscription.page.ts:112:58)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
(anonymous) @ subscription.page.ts:170
rejected @ tslib.es6.mjs:119
push.96084._ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:409
onInvoke @ core.mjs:25450
push.96084._ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:408
push.96084.Zone.run @ zone.js:169
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1326
push.96084._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:443
onInvokeTask @ core.mjs:25437
push.96084._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:442
push.96084.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:214
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:632
Promise.then (async)
nativeScheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:608
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:619
push.96084._ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:433
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:320
push.96084._ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:423
push.96084.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:257
push.96084.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:277
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:1316
resolvePromise @ zone.js:1253
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1169
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1185
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1577
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1351
Ctor.then @ zone.js:1576
resolvePromise @ zone.js:1220
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1169
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1185
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.mjs:116
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1351
adopt @ tslib.es6.mjs:116
step @ tslib.es6.mjs:120
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.mjs:121
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1351
__awaiter @ tslib.es6.mjs:117
subscribe @ subscription.page.ts:108
SubscriptionPage_Template_button_click_22_listener @ template.html:17
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.mjs:14949
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.mjs:14987
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.mjs:465
push.96084._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:443
onInvokeTask @ core.mjs:25437
push.96084._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:442
push.96084.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:214
push.96084.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:525
invokeTask @ zone.js:1727
globalCallback @ zone.js:1758
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1794
subscription.page.ts:171 IntegrationError: Invalid value for createPaymentMethod: card was `payment` Element, which cannot be used to create card PaymentMethods.
    at v3/:1:493961
    at ne (v3/:1:184827)
    at re (v3/:1:185082)
    at v3/:1:337961
    at Xr (v3/:1:338011)
    at e.<anonymous> (v3/:1:388774)
    at e._createPaymentMethod (v3/:1:91285)
    at e.o (v3/:1:422082)
    at SubscriptionPage.<anonymous> (subscription.page.ts:112:58)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

And i am using test credentials for card visa 4242424242424242  Any 3 digits    Any future date

What i am asking is:

1. The key i use is live not test but i want to test first but when i put test key i am getting errors. So why it works with live key and not with test?
2. I am getting client secret because i use createIntent php function in  ngAfterViewInit() before the user send the card values with the subscribe function in which i use createIntent again to get customer Id. That's wrong right? But how can i use payment Element otherwise?
3. How can i fix the error i am displaying here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The client_secret is obtained from a PaymentIntent, which is created via the Subscription. So basically you create the Subscription on your backend and when you do so you want to use `payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete'` and also expand the `latest_invoice.payment_intent` so that you can access the PaymentIntent's client_secret. You then pass that client_secret to your frontend to initialize Elements. See: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements for full docs on this flow.

Comment: ok, but in my code i create the customer when the user presses the 'Subscribe' button thus the subscribe function in initialised. But in order to use the payment elements with the desired inputs provided by stripe i have to create the client secret  before async subscribe() function right?

Comment: You would either create the Subscription on page-load or some earlier trigger, or you can use the deferred-intent flow: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred?platform=web&type=subscription

Comment: I updated the code to show you more details. Thanks @bismarck